# How would I reverse yellow stains resulting from sealing a marble table top?

Tags: sealing, sanding, stone, marble, sealer

I sealed a **new polished marble table top** with a granite sealer that also works on marble.
The discoloration is slight, but I'd like to remove it. What's the best way to do this?

I've read about "color enhancers" that accentuate color, but I'm looking for something that would reverse that effect and fade the yellow. Does something like that exist?

I've read that using bleach is not a good idea.
I'm considering sanding it at 220 grit—wise move?

Comment: I'd try polish first before sanding it. I know from experience that steel wool dulls granite.

Answer (score 1):

Sanding even with 220 grit requires feathering and also making sure you go to 600 grit or higher to match existing polish. A product I use as a professional called diamond renew works wonders it is acidic and it is similar to glass etching products.

It must be applied and removed in sections exactly as the instructions say.

As warning: it is a lot of physical work and  it must be used across the entire surface after sanding. 
 It is a difficult process but renews the surface to a factory or near factory finish. You must not let it dry on the marble or get into cracks  as it will continue to eat in to the stone and create pits.

If after feather sanding the spot another option besides diamond renew you might try to buff the surface with  rouge. 
Use a variable speed buffer on low to medium speed with enough rouge to bring out the shine but not so much it leaves residue on the surface. Start light and work up.

However diamond renew is my preference it is just very difficult and you should if possible practice on a piece of marble before you attack the counter top.

Lastly marble is not granite...lemon juice can discolor marble and it scratches easily so sand lightly ....if you are not sure how to feather sand do not attempt it until you understand it. Also please remember products that claim are for both granite and marble should be used with caution. I would recommend using an "ager" after you finish sanding and polishing...not a sealant.

Comment: Breaking your answer into paragraphs makes it easier to read and follow.  You have some good points, but the wall of text makes it hard to consume.

Answer (score 0):

Diluted muriatic acid 10% and water will take the sealer out but will also slightly etch the marble , you need to use gloves and have fresh air as the fumes can get quite strong.
Try it in a corner to verify you get the results you are looking for , you may need a stronger solution but don’t go above 30% with lots of fresh air. 
Any place that sells pool supplies will carry muriatic acid and some home improvement stores. It is regularly used to etch cement prior to sealing or painting. as far as sanding I would use a much finer wet/dry paper minimum of 600 grit and 1000 or better for the finish pass with a dual action sander.and finish with a polish compound

Comment: I concur, acid eats all, it can't be beat as a deep cleaning agent.

Comment: be extremely careful with muriatic acid. On an ultra smooth polished marble or granite, it may etch the finish, losing the polished shine.  Test in a small obscure area. Repolishing a large surface is not an easy task for a DIYer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution might be a Stripper cleaner. Tile Doctor has a tile and stone cleaner, any acid will damage your stone.